# Get json array from Web api into c#

Tags: c#, json, uwp

I´m having a `SQL` database and I want to get the `SQL` values from a `API` into c# code. The `API` contains multiple rooms with room attributes, and each room have a `Guid` as a id.

This code works but I only get one room out of this:

```
string url = "https://api.booking.com/api/room/35bf3c4d-9b5b-40fd-bcf4-a4c2c6c564bc";

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

string response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);

var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class2>(response);
```

When i remove the `id` (Guid) to get all rooms i get this error when i launch the application:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Class2' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
>   Path '', line 1, position 1.'

This is the code without the Guid:

```
string url = "https://api.booking.com/api/room";

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

string response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);

var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class2>(response);
```

My question is in short terms "How can i get a json array from a api?".

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

This is the code for class2:

```
public class Class2
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public int seats { get; set; }
    public int? availableFrom { get; set; }
    public int? availableTo { get; set; }
}
```

And this is a longer output from a room in the `API`:

```
[
{
    "name": "Rum 1",
    "id": "a31d1fc8-df29-419c-8308-f8bc884b378e",
    "seats": 10,
    "availableFrom": null,
    "availableTo": null
  },
  {
    "name": "Rum 2",
    "id": "7defd34d-222d-4980-b28f-e616e8b9003c",
    "seats": 5,
    "availableFrom": null,
    "availableTo": null
  },
  {
    "name": "Skrubben",
    "id": "b20390ff-703b-4d80-8c2f-32c0f27158bc",
    "seats": 5,
    "availableFrom": 10,
    "availableTo": 11
  },
  {
    "name": "Hangaren",
    "id": "b89cbacd-c738-477f-aff2-7f22c2b2cd5c",
    "seats": 100,
    "availableFrom": null,
    "availableTo": null
  },
  {
    "name": "Tv-rummet",
    "id": "ea6a290f-209b-4ccb-91a4-65d82a674bad",
    "seats": 10,
    "availableFrom": null,
    "availableTo": null
  },
  {
    "name": "Projektor-rummet",
    "id": "3136a56a-4a28-4939-aca8-806534c808f7",
    "seats": 12,
    "availableFrom": null,
    "availableTo": null
  },
  {
    "name": "Skolsalen",
    "id": "05f73582-3734-453f-aeb3-36daf8884912",
    "seats": 30,
    "availableFrom": null,
    "availableTo": null
  }
]
```

Comment: Try `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class2[]>(response);`

Comment: When I do that i cant reach all the attributes inside the rooms (for example _Name_) @DmitryEgorov

Comment: Perhaps, objects returned in the array by `.../api/room` are not as detailed as a single object instance returned by `.../api/room/{guid}`. Could you please provide a sample output of the two API requests and `Class2` definition as well?

Comment: Check my edit @DmitryEgorov

Comment: Seems to be output from `.../api/room/{guid}`. What's the output from `.../api/room`?

Comment: Again in the edit :) @DmitryEgorov

Comment: In this case the attributes (and the `name` particularly) should be available: https://dotnetfiddle.net/y5gE96

Comment: Thanks for the help! ts solved :) @DmitryEgorov

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error suggests,

> You are deserializing an array into a class. It will never work. You
>   need to deserialize it into either an array or a list using the below code snippet.

Try: 
`var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Class2>>(response);` 
or 
`var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class2[]>(response);`
 and it will work fine.

EDIT 1:

```
foreach(var room in data)
{
   string id = room.id;
   string name = room.name;

   // and so on
}
```

Comment: Okey, i tried the first example but when i do that i can't reach the attributes in the rooms.

Comment: With first example, you get a list of rooms. Now try to iterate it using a foreach loop and find the attributes.

Comment: Okey, i will come back with the results :)

Comment: Sure, post the code snippet if possible for more clarity.

Comment: Haha, sorry but i don't really have the knowledge to write the foreach loop :(

Comment: I have updated my answer with foreach loop. You should try it.

Answer (score 0):

multiple Class2 objects must be use List or Array type to convert them，
you can try  `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Class2>>(response)`